# minLength not working with String in JSON Schema

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema

I am pretty new to node, so might be the case I am using the JSON Schema not correctly, please correct me if I am wrong.

I have been using the npm module named jsonschema.

And for using validation I am using it like:

```
var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
var instance = {
    "user_id"   :   "jesus",
    "password"  :   "password"
};
var schema = {
    "id" : "Login_login",
    "type" : "object",
    "additionalProperties" : false,
    "properties" : {
        "user_id": {
            "type" : "string",
            "required": true,
            "minLenth" : 8,
            "maxLength" : 10,
            "description": "User id to login."
        },
        "password" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "required": true,
            "minLength" : 8,
            "maxLength" : 10,
            "description" : "password to login."
        }
    }
};
var result = v.validate(instance, schema);
console.log('>>>>>> ' + result);
```

But the point is result is not having an error although the the **minLength** of **user_id** is kept as 8 but I have passed 5 characters, so if I am not wrong result should throw an error for the same, Why is it so
:(

Comment: Notice how you misspelled `minLength` as `minLenth`...

Comment: #facepalm, I wasted almost 1 hour and then you came as a life saver....
lol 
thanks a lot...
i am deleting the question
can't face that much of humiliation....
:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema itself needs validation.  Its "user_id" condition "minLength" spelled without a "g".